# The page needs to be refreshed manually then show API data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I am working on a real estate project, and use React for the frontend, Firebase as the backend, I got a problem with the category page below:

There are two different categories of this project, one for sale, and the other one for rent, when I click each category, we will be redirected to the corresponding page ( page of sale OR rent listings );

Every time when I click and enter the page of sale listings, it shows "No listing for sale" first (please see the screenshot), after I refreshed this page manually, then the sale listings came out.

### The first time when I enter the page of  sale listings:

[image: first enter screenshot]

##After I refreshed this page manually:
[image: after refresh manually screenshot]

But when I click and enter the page of rental listings, everything works well.

Can anyone help me with this? I really appreciate it.

#category.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  query,
  where,
  orderBy,
  limit,
  startAfter,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase.config";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import ListingItem from "../components/ListingItem";

function Category(props) {
  const [listings, setListings] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [lastFetchedListing, setLastFetchedListing] = useState(null);

  const params = useParams();

  const fetchListings = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const listingsRef = collection(db, "listings");
  
      const q = query(
        listingsRef,
        where("type", "==", params.categoryName),
        orderBy("timestamp", "desc"),
        limit(10)
      );

      // Execute query
      const querySnap = await getDocs(q);

      const lastVisible = querySnap.docs[querySnap.docs.length - 1];
      setLastFetchedListing(lastVisible);

      const listings = [];

      querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
        return listings.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        });
      });

      setListings(listings);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Could not fetch listings");
    }
  }, [params.categoryName]);

  useEffect(() => { 
    fetchListings();
  }, [fetchListings]);


  const onFetchMoreListings = async () => {
    try {
      const listingsRef = collection(db, "listings");

      const q = query(
        listingsRef,
        where("type", "==", params.categoryName),
        orderBy("timestamp", "desc"),
        startAfter(lastFetchedListing),
        limit(10)
      );
 
      const querySnap = await getDocs(q);

      const lastVisible = querySnap.docs[querySnap.docs.length - 1];
      setLastFetchedListing(lastVisible);

      const listings = [];

      querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
        return listings.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        });
      });

      setListings((prevState) => [...prevState, ...listings]);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Could not fetch listings");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="category container">
      <p className="pageHeader">
      {params.categoryName === "rent" ? "Places for rent" : "Places for sale"}
      </p>

      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : listings && listings.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <div>
            <ul className="">
              {listings.map((listing) => (
                <ListingItem
                  listing={listing.data}
                  id={listing.id}
                  key={listing.id}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>

          {lastFetchedListing && (
            <p className="loadMore" onClick={onFetchMoreListings}>
              Load More
            </p>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>No listings for {params.categoryName}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Category;
```

Comment: Curiously, the URL path is `"/category/sale"` but it seems the `categoryName` in the code isn't equal to "sale" and renders the `"Places for rent"` string, but then below that in the same render renders the `"No listing for sale"` text correctly. The `useCallback` is incorrectly using `params.categoryNam` as a dependency instead of `params.categoryName`. Does `listings` in the `fetchListings` callback have the value you expect prior to enqueueing the state update?

Comment: Hi Drew, nice to see you again. 1)Just checked and found that the error of "Places for rent" came from {params.categoryName === "sale" ? "Places for sale": "Places for rent"}, I modified it as {... "rent" ? "Places for rent" : "Places for sale"},then it came out"Places for sale. 2) corrected it as params.categoryName, thanks for the heads up. 3)Yes, listings in fechListings() It's an empty array.

Comment: The initial `listings` state value is null, so it seems the mounting logic is working and updates this state... to an empty array. Double check the `fetchListings` handler and the values it is referencing to fetch data from your backend. Make sure you are passing the values you *think* you are.

Comment: Hi Drew, my app is broken for some reason, so I made a new one, then the previous problem became to--- "fetchListings()" fetched an empty array. I agree with you, there should be something wrong with the fetchListings handler and the values. I am new to firebase, I will do more research and see if I can figure out this issue. Thanks so much for your advice : )